# UpgradeSchema not working in Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

I have make

> setup:upgrade with changing **module version**

here is my code:

```
<?php namespace Tatva\ProductImport\Setup;

  use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

  class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
      {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function upgrade(
    SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
      $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
            'product_categories',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true
            ]
        );
      $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
            'product_url',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true
            ]
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
            'product_download',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'length'=>11,
                'default'=>0,
                'nullable' => true
            ]
        )
      ;
    }
    $installer->endSetup();
 }
}
```

Comment: `product_import_details` is your custom table? Did you create it?

Comment: yes i have create using install schema before

Comment: Can you please upload your module.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your module version should be **1.0.1** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tatva_ProductImport" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">      
    </module>
</config>
```

Replace this below code in your upgradeschema file. I changed if condition format :

```
<?php
namespace Tatva\ProductImport\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {        
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
              $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
                    'product_categories',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true
                    ]
                );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
              $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
                    'product_url',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true
                    ]
                );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
              $installer->getTable('product_import_details'),
                    'product_download',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        'length'=>11,
                        'default'=>0,
                        'nullable' => true
                    ]
                );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan.
It's working!!!!

Can you please tell why module version 1.0.1 require or give reference link for it?

Comment: When upgradeschema execute at that time, it will check module version and in this file, we add code like that if module version is greater that 1.0.1, then new column will be add. So, in your code old module version was found. So, before execute upgrade schema we need to change module version in module.xml.

Comment: Ohh... i missed that line to follow..

Btw thanks rohan!!

Comment: My Pleasure :) Happy coding !! :)